# GNUplot--Change steps of yrange

Tags: gnuplot

I'm learning GNUplot. I need to change steps in which Y values increase while plotting my graph.xrange command will change range but steps. Ex. I have data like this
1 1000
2 1500
3 1
4 200
...

By default GNUplot is taking Y range as[0,5000] which is OK for me. but y values are increasing in steps of 500, I want to increase in steps of 200. Is it possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the setting `ytics`.

```
set ytics 200
```

There is also a setting for the smaller tics, which are called *minor tics*. The corresponding setting is `mytics`.